# iOS: Is there any way to fake the user's locale?

Tags: ios, localization, nsbundle

I'm interested in allowing my users to choose the language / locale my app appears to them in.  I have figured out how to load the right bundle, choose the correct strings files, etc.  However, some system items I still seem to have no control over.  Switch controls, for example.

Is there any way for me to tell the system that this app should now behave in a specific language, rather than the user's current system setting?

Comment: Whoa-whoo. `method_setImplementation(class_getInstanceMethod([NSLocale class], @selector(currentLocale)), (IMP)spoofedImpl);`?

Comment: Any way to do it without swizzling?

Comment: Have you tried creating a category for NSLocale to return the locale of your choosing for the class methods?

Comment: @MarcusAdams thats worser than method swizzling because override method on category have undefined behaviour

Comment: @Mike Become a software developer at Apple working on UIKit, create a secret/private method that allows you to do this, put it in the next release of iOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The least hacky way is via `NSUserDefaults`: The locale is determined by `AppleLocale` (the locale ID as a string) and the language is determined by the first match in `AppleLanguages` (an array of language IDs); your app can override these defaults *for your app only*. To check if it's overridden by your app, you can use something like `[defaults persistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]] objectForKey:@"AppleLocale"]`. To remove the override, use `-removeObjectForKey:`.

Whichever way you do it, you'll probably have to [relaunch the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238979/how-programatically-restart-iphone-app) when changing languages; OS X and iOS apps simply aren't designed to change language at runtime (on OS X, only newly launched apps see the language change; on iOS the system kills all apps to change language).

I added this feature to make switching languages easier for development/testing; I have no idea whether this will fail the App Store review process.

Comment: Thanks @tc. It sounds like this is probably something to stay away from, but I appreciate the detailed option.